# Change Value of Hidden Field using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following form where i want to assign value of "R.EmailAddress" field to a Hidden field
"email_From".

I tried to use the function doCalculate in Javascript but its not assigning R.EmailAddress to email_From, is it because of input type="image" ??

```
<form name="eMail" method="post" action="/emailform.asp" >
<input type="text" name="R.EmailAddress" class="textfield_contact" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="email_From" value="contact@shopbyus.com">
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" border="0" name="submit" value="Submit" `onClick="doCalculate(this.form)">`
```

My Javascript function looks like below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function doCalculate(theForm){
    var aVal = theForm.R.EmailAddress.value;
    theForm.email_From.value=aVal;
    alert(aVal);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Just to make sure...are you closing your script tag in your JavaScript function?

Comment: There are backticks in your code, before the onClick and after the end of the image tag. Have you tried removing those?

Comment: Just to make sure...are you closing your script tag in your JavaScript function?
.. Yes its closed

Answer (score 3):

Since "R" is not a property of the object, you have to use ["R.EmailAddress"]

```
function doCalculate(theForm){
    var aVal = theForm["R.EmailAddress"].value;
    theForm.email_From.value=aVal;
    alert(aVal);
}
```

Comment: With the current, invalid HTML, I think that the function is not even called ;)

Comment: Which event shall i use onclick on < input type="image " or onsubmit() on the form tag

Answer (score 0):

`theForm.R.EmailAddress.value`

This looks at the object `theForm`, finds a property `R` from that object, then finds a property `EmailAddress` from that object, then gets the `value` from that object. This clearly isn't what you mean: you're looking for the `R.EmailAddress` property of the `theForm` object.

Since `.` can't be used in property names with the dot member notation, you'll have to use square bracket notation instead:

```
theForm['R.EmailAddress'].value;
```

See the [MDN page on member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) for more information on these syntaxesx.

Comment: Thanks i tried that but still nothing, shall i use onclick on < input type="image " or onsubmit() on the form tag ?

Comment: @Nilesh I think you should try a tutorial that doesn't follow late 1990s coding styles... It would be better to use `onsubmit`, and it would be better to learn about the DOM and better ways to access and manipulate elements.